# How to style links before line break element

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to style only the links that appear before the line break element?

I would like to style Link 1 and Link 2 only.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a> and <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <br>
        word word word word word word <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I know I can easily inline the style but I was wondering if there is another way to go about doing this.

Comment: CSS classes exist precisely for this kind of thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :not to select only those a elements that are not after a br element.

This is a simple example. You could get more complex and ignore all a elements that are children of elements which follow a br for example.

```css
a:not(br ~ a){
    color: red;
}
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a> and <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <br>
            word word word word word word <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use a [sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

```css
a {
    background-color: pink;
}

br + a {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a> and <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <br>
            word word word word word word <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I thought you wanted to style links before the line break, not after?

Comment: I do. I think the below solution works better for me... ie: a:not(br ~ a) Thank you!

Comment: You create a default style for all links, and then you can override or update it with a style just for links after a line break.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any selector that would select specifically that anchor but you can do this:

```css
a:not(br + a) {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a> and <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <br>
            word word word word word word <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

But I wouldn't do it. Better to put them into a div and style that way.

Comment: This will also select every anchor element that comes after a br element except for if it comes immediately after the br.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML `id` attribute, `id="link_1"`, then format it with CSS.

Use ID selector like this: `#link_1`, so only `link_1` get the style.

For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            #link_1 {
                text-decoration: none;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="" id="link_1"> A red link </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `:has()` selector if you're happy with it [not working in Firefox](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas) (but will soon, hopefully).

If you use this without the `:has()` selector, you will change the color of all your anchors, but not the ones after a line break.

If you only want to style the anchors in this manner when they are in a list or any other condition, replace the wildcard selector with the relevant element or a utility class.

```css
/* Style only the anchors in elements that have line breaks, but not the ones after the line break */
*:has(br) > a:not(br ~ a) {
  color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a> and <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <br>
        word word word word word word <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">I won't be hotpink</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```